# Postgres Dump is strucked in eclipse, language used is python

Tags: python, postgresql

Please refer below python code, and let me know what wrong or what need to be done to make it work.

The problem i faced is, Eclipse get strucked  and backup file is empty.

```
import os
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "test hello"

    localhost = 'localhost'
    port = '5432'
    role = 'serverdb_user'
    dump_dir = '/home/backupfile/'
    db_username = 'empserverdb_user'
    db_names = 'emp1'

    try:
        bkp_file = 'backup1'
        file_path = os.path.join(dump_dir, bkp_file)
        print file_path
        dumper_cmd = ['pg_dump', '-h', localhost, '-p', port, '-U', db_username, '--role', role, '-W', '-Fc', '-v', '-f', file_path, db_names]
        print dumper_cmd
        subprocess.check_output(dumper_cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
        print("Couldn't back up database {0}: pg_dump returned {1} with output {2}".format(db_names, ex.returncode, ex.output))
    except Exception, ex:
        print("Couldn't backup database {0}: unexpected error {1}".format(db_names, ex))
```

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe you could check the errno from the exec call (could be that `pg_dump` is not in the path) Or the errorlog from the postgres DB (connection problems, authorisation, typos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, [use proper exception handling](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions). Either use `sys.exc_info` to get the exception context, or use an exception capture that gets the exception in a local, like `except Exception, ex:`

Additionally, there's no reason to use `shell=True` here, and many reasons not to. Let the `subprocess` module deal with shell escaping if you're on a platform like Windows that doesn't have a proper exec system call. Pass an array of arguments to `subprocess`. It's way easier to get right, and your program will still work if there's a space in the database name, file path, username, or whatever.

Finally, use `subprocess.check_call`, or preferably `check_output` on a newer Python. You're failing to check the result of the call, so you won't know if something went wrong. `check_output` stores the process `stderr` in the `output` field of the `CalledProcessException`, making it convenient for reporting errors.

Otherwise, use `check_call` and use the `subprocess` module's I/O redirection features to write the `pg_dump` output to a file. Then report that file name in the error so the user can go look at it.

Something like (untested):

```
    try:
        bkp_file = 'backup1'
        file_path = os.path.join(dump_dir, bkp_file)
        dumper_cmd = ['pg_dump', '-h', localhost, '-p', port, '-U', db_username, '--role', role, '-W', '-Fc', '-v', '-f', file_path, db_name]
        subprocess.check_output(dumper_cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
        print("Couldn't back up database {0}: pg_dump returned {1} with output {2}".format(db_name, ex.returncode, ex.output)
    except Exception, ex:
        print("Couldn't backup database {0}: unexpected error {1}".format(db_name, ex))
```

Comment: As well as updated the post with latest code, still same problem @Craig Ringer

Comment: Again same problem, my eclipse get hanged and file contain 0 size... I'm using Linux env @Craig Ringer .

Comment: @Hariharan Sounds like your `pg_dump` might be pausing waiting for password input. Add the `-w` argument to your `pg_dump` argument list to tell it never to prompt for a password.

Comment: yes, you are right.... an hour before i fixed the problem. Thanks for your detail explanation. Great work @Craig Ringer.

Comment: i accept you answer, which help to optimize my code as better.