# subprocess.check_ouput is hanging up in eclipse and not taking backup for pg_dump in python language

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql-9.1

postgres dump is not working properly, I run the below python program through eclipse with linux(ubuntu) background OS.

The problem is eclipse get hanged up and trace information as well as backup file is empty.

```
import os
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "test hello"

    localhost = 'localhost'
    port = '5432'
    role = 'serverdb_user'
    dump_dir = '/home/backupfile/'
    db_username = 'empserverdb_user'
    db_names = 'emp1'

    try:
        bkp_file = 'backup1'
        file_path = os.path.join(dump_dir, bkp_file)
        print file_path
        dumper_cmd = ['pg_dump', '-h', localhost, '-p', port, '-U', db_username, '--role', role, '-W', '-Fc', '-v', '-f', file_path, db_names]
        print dumper_cmd
        subprocess.check_output(dumper_cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
        print("Couldn't back up database {0}: pg_dump returned {1} with output {2}".format(db_names, ex.returncode, ex.output))
    except Exception, ex:
        print("Couldn't backup database {0}: unexpected error {1}".format(db_names, ex))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem get resolved by placing assigning password to env. As well as people suggestion on post  [Postgres Dump is strucked in eclipse, language used is python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882836/postgres-dump-is-strucked-in-eclipse-language-used-is-python)